# How to write unittest.mock for input function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, async-await

The main function for the test:

```
async def start_script():
    script = int(input("Введите:\n1 для запуска парсера видео\n2 для запуска загрузчика видео: \n"))
    if script == 1:
        number = int(input("Введите количество видео для парсинга: "))
        # await main.info_videos(number=number)
    elif script == 2:
        number_pc = int(input("Введите номер ПК: "))
        count_video = int(input("Количество повторных публикаций: "))
        print("Введите диапазон времени для публикации (в минутах)")
        number1 = int(input("От (в минутах): "))
        number2 = int(input("До (в минутах): "))
        await get_video_process(number1, number2, number_pc, count_video)
    else:
        print("Ошибка ввода!")
        await start_script()


asyncio.run(start_script())
```

Unittest for this code:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from web import start_script


class TestStartScript(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("builtins.input", side_effect=["1", "5"])
    def test_start_script(self, mock_input):
        self.assertIsNone(start_script())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

After I ran this test, it started but waits for console input, even though it should do it automatically. So the script stops in one place, and just waits for the data to be entered. How to solve this?
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anhPa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace this line:

```
asyncio.run(start_script())
```

with:

```
if __name__ == 'main':
    asyncio.run(start_script())
```

and change your test function to:

```
@patch("builtins.input", side_effect=["1", "5"])
def test_start_script(self, mock_input):
    self.assertIsNone(asyncio.run(start_script()))
```